# having trouble with parse sdk and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I'm trying to do parse push with my node.js server and am getting `"unauthorized"`errors.

i tried looking up the documentation but couldn't find anything on github with the module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse

Is the nodejs parse sdk still being maintained?

Here is my code

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
Parse.initialize(config.get('parse_app_id'), config.get('parse_master_key'));

Parse.Push.send({
    channels: phoneNumbers,
    data: {
        alert: message
    }
}, {
    success: function () {
        callback();
    },
    error: function (error) {
        callback(error);
    }
});
```

I tried the same push call with node-parse-api and it worked.

Comment: Have you tried updating the package with npm? It seems to be working for me after I tried updating. Also, did you try with the JS key, along with the master key as the 3rd param to the initialize call?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me with promises:

```
var Parse = require('Parse').Parse;

Parse.initialize(...);

Parse.Push.send({
  channels: [],
  data: {parsekey: 'parseval'}
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Output:

```
{ result: true }
```

The npm package is the official JS library, so I would be very surprised if it was obsoleted.

Comment: looks very similar - what is the `parsekey:parseval` is that a message text key of some sort?

Comment: Yes, it is just test data (Parse.Push.send has required options).

Comment: where is the documentation for the node.js sdk - I couldn't find the github readme - is it the same as their client side javascript sdk?

Comment: also tried with promises and I'm still getting `{ code: undefined, message: 'unauthorized' }`